# Submit credit card contribution error - configure live settings for payment processor

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, paypal

Just upgraded to civicrm 4.7.24.  Tried to use the submit credit card contribution and get an error message telling me to configure live settings for payment processor.  I have been using credit cards for events pages and contribution pages for years.  They still work. I am using paypal standard.

Comment: Did you review your payment processor settings? Is paypal your default?

Comment: May be worth checking one of the demo sites and seeing if you can see any obvious differences in Payment Processors

Comment: I tried demo site but was unable to look at or change payment processor

Comment: did you get this figured out?